# WSO2: trp.vfs variables end up in request headers (no matter what)

Tags: security, http-headers, vfs, wso2-esb

I encountered some strange behavior while analyzing the http headers in the following treatment

```
| sftp folder | ==vfs=> | ESB processing | ===http===> REST endpoint
```

### IN

Files are read from the folder with the following **inbound endpoint**:

```xml
<inboundEndpoint name="aaa2bbb-aaaFolder" onError="aaa2bbb-errors" protocol="file" sequence="aaa2bbb-processFiles" statistics="enable" suspend="false" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="interval">5000</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.LockReleaseSameNode">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.AutoLockRelease">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FailedRecordsFileName">vfs-move-failed-records.properties</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FailedRecordsFileDestination">repository/conf/</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveFailedRecordTimestampFormat">dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FailedRecordNextRetryDuration">3000</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter key="gov:/filesystem/fromAAA.txt" name="transport.vfs.FileURI"/>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileURI">${registry:gov:/filesystem/fromAAA.txt}/success</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName">response.xml</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.DistributedLock">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">^CMDE.*\.zip|^(?!tmp).*\.xml</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAttribute">none</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAscending">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.CreateFolder">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Build">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

### OUT

The problem is:

> vfs variables such as `File-Uri`, `File-Path` or `Last-Modified` systematically end up in the **Headers** of the requests sent to the REST **endpoint**

Not only this isn't quite elegant but it raises a real **security issue**, for sftp `File-Uri` include *username* and *passwords*:

```sh
sftp://${user}:${password}@some_domain.com/somePath
```

### Attempts

I tried several variable names to remove this specific header in my sequences:

- `fileURI`
- `file-uri`
- `File-Uri`
- `FILE-URI`
- `transport.vfs.fileURI`

```xml
<header name="${some-name}" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
```

but those variables **always** end up in the headers. How should I fix it? Is it a matter of tuning the **inbound-endpoint** properly to encapsulate its transport variables from the ones of the **call**?

[**environment**]

- wso2ei 6.5.0
- fileconnector-2.0.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but I used the following to remove all transport headers.

```
<property name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
```

Or use the following to remove headers.

```
<property name="<name of the header to be removed>" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
```

Maybe its worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. Unfortunately, none of the options achieve what I am looking for. The first one removes everything, including necessary headers. The second has simply no effect. What a messy product

Comment: That's really weird. Can you try with <property name="<name of the header to be removed>" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>.  If this does not work maybe a workaround would be 1.) save the needed headers in properties 2.) remove all "TRANSPORT_HEADERS" 3.) set the needed headers with <header>. Not sure if one of this works.